# What am I by SC #4

Tags: riddle, word

I have won 3 at the same time

I did this 3 times, and actually won 4 the last time

There 19 similar to me in the world with this achievement,

but after 2015 I am above them all

I am from the Oceania

1 without Ramon, other 2 thanks to Ramon

Hint:

> from Oceania is real. Not a trick.

Hint 2:

> Related with sports, but not a person

Comment: Assuming its sports, and that ocenia is used because most server based games often use that term, so its probably a game / e-sport.

Comment: Can't figure out the 19 part. The whole thing about Ramon was easy to find

Comment: well you should be able to find the 19 part if you found first 2 clues. it is for self proof to be sure. don't hesitate answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> Auckland City Football Club

I have won 3 at the same time
I did this 3 times, and actually won 4 the last time
There 19 similar to me in the world with this achievement,

> Refers to winning the Treble (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treble_(association_football)#Annual_and_seasonal_trebles)

but after 2015 I am above them all

> I suppose because they are the only team to do this 3 times.

I am from the Oceania

> The club is in the Oceania Football Confederation

1 without Ramon, other 2 thanks to Ramon

> Ramon is the club's current coach. If I had time right now to fact check I suppose I'd find he was only the coach two of the seasons that they did this

Note

> This was very straightforward to find, especially with the hints. I picked New Zealand randomly based on the term "Oceania" and a search of "New Zealand Ramon sports" did the rest.

Comment: Gj man. Well, even with hints no one was interested. I am trying ti make research based riddles but I guess people don't like them after my first.

Answer (score 3):

The answer should be

> Tiger Woods

I have won 3 at the same time, and actually won 4 the last time

> Woods victory at the 2013 Players Championship also marked a win in
>  his 300th PGA Tour start. He also won golf tournaments in his 100th
>  (in 2000) and 200th (in 2006) tour starts.
>
>  He is one of five players (along with Gene Sarazen, Ben Hogan, Gary
>  Player, and Jack Nicklaus) to have won all four professional major
>  championships in his career, known as the Career Grand Slam, and was
>  the youngest to do so

There 19 similar to me in the world with this achievement,
but after 2015 I am above them all

> Woods is the only player to have won all four professional major
>  championships in a row

I am from the Ocenia
Perhaps related to the following one..

> “I am really good at playing video games,” Woods said. “That’s
>  basically how I pass my time.”

1 without Ramon, Another 2 thanks to Ramon
Perhaps not sure though

> Woods visits with students from Hopeworks n’ Camden; From L-R – Sean
>  Dougherty, Ramon Alverado, Jonathan Lugo, Tiger Woods, and Luis Solis

Comment: not correct. I really mean it when I tell "I am from the Oceania", and 19 similar to me doesn't explain it either